# Python Automated Email When Script Fails or Has Error

Tags: python

I have several automated Python programs that take .csv files and runs different processes with the files. I'm trying to figure out how to have Python send me the actual error message if any type of error arises with any of my processes. I have found a lot of posts on this and I can get Python to send emails but I can't figure out how to get it to only send an email when an error occurs and send me that exact error. Any help is greatly appreciated! Here's a sample piece of code that I would want an error email for:

```
def main():
    configuration = whg_common.readApplicationConfiguration()
try:
 rows = []
 d = {}
 with open("/Users/Dell/prewhg-cleansender/File_Processing/dailyfile/Test2020_20220521_032516.csv") as f:
    spamreader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    with open("/Users/Dell/prewhg-cleansender/File_Processing/dailyfile/output.csv", 'w') as g:
     for row in spamreader:
        rows.append(row)
        row['StreetNum'] = row['Address1'].split(' ')[0]
        row['Finitial'] = row['Last Name'][0:1]
        row['UniqueID'] = row['Client ID'] + row['StreetNum'] + row['Zip'] + row['Zip+4'] + row['Finitial']
        row['date'] = dateutil.getToday().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
        unique = row['UniqueID']
        if unique not in d:
            d[unique] = row


            del row['StreetNum']
            del row['Finitial']
            #del row['UniqueID']
            fileutil.writeFile("/Users/Dell/prewhg-cleansender/File_Processing/dailyfile/output.csv", rows)

except Exception:
    print("An exception occurred")
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')



    consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    fileHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename="error.log", maxBytes=1024000, backupCount=10, mode="a")
    fileHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    smtpHandler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost=('email.xxxxx.com', 25),
                                               fromaddr="Automation@xxxxx.net",
                                               toaddrs="abc@xxx.net",
                                               subject="Automation Error!",
                                               credentials=("automation@xxxxx.net", "xxxxx"),
                                               secure=())
    smtpHandler.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    smtpHandler.setFormatter(formatter)



    logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
    logger.addHandler(smtpHandler)

    #this will be written only to console"
    logger.debug("this is a debug message")
    #this will be written to console and file
    logger.info("this is an info message")
    #this will go to email only
    logger.critical("Situation is critical. Come to office immediately.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: check out try except in python. add send email option to the exception block. [Error handling - tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: The indentation isn't format.

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach would be

```
try:
    # Do Important Stuff here
     print(x)
except:
  print("An exception occurred") 
  #Executed when error occures, so send email...
```

Comment: Not totally correct. You shouldn’t have a bare except block. At the very least, you should use except Exception.

Comment: I got this to work with adding except Exception but how can I get the actual Python error message sent to me and not just an email with "An error has occurred"?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My code has been updated to include the error email. What I'm trying to do is have Python send me the actual Python error and not what I have plugged in under logger.critical. The code is working fine that I posted just need the actual Python error if it fails. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I finally found the answer to what I'm looking for. It needs to look like this in order to get the actual Python error: logger.critical("Situation is critical. Come to office immediately.", exc_info=True)